# Oracle ORA-40474 inconsistency

Tags: json, oracle

I am getting ORA-40474 when I am trying to execute

```
select json_object('test' value 'abcdé') from dual;

select json_object('test' value 'abcdéf') from dual;
```

But this one works

```
select json_object('test' value 'abcdéfg') from dual;
```

My database is `NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8MSWIN1252`

This does not make any sense as why the last select should work when the others don't.

Answer (score 2):

Replace for this:

```
select json_object('test' value 'abcdé' FORMAT JSON) from dual;
```